# Linq Query Entity Framework? passing multiple conditions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

[This is my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hn72S.png)
Now when user select BankAccounts from AccTypeDecs i want AccHeadId that is 100 in this case to be store in a variable any idea how can i od this using linq ?

Comment: Please some more information. Do you want a Linq-query to work on the grid "table" (see answer below !), or do you want to Linq-query the tables that make up the grid result ? In that case a Linq-query with multiple tables is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this ?

```
table.Where(item => item.AccTypeDecs == "BankAccounts").Select(item => item.AccHeadId).First();
```

The WHERE is the condition, the select filter which field is returned.